# c# T4 template engine can't import "System.Xml"

Tags: t4

I use the method in [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519(v=vs.120).aspx) ("*Processing Text Templates by using a Custom Host*").

This allows me to use T4 programmatically (template can be available in runtime).

But there is a problem that in the template code I can't use

```
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" #>
```

I would get message like :

> error CS0234: Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to [reference the assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx). The import statement is equivalent to the using statement in C#. You can reference the System.Xml assembly by using:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: if the error throws from included file, ensure that the included file has no Custom Tool selected.